# Javascript / Jquery returns cfquery value of 'no' as false and 'yes' as true

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have an interesting problem.
I Have a jquery ajax command to get data from a MySQL table (code to follow)
When i then build my table values that should be yes are now true and values of valse are not false.

Here is the function on my coldfusion page.
Nothing fancy, im calling a cfc method

```
function getitems()
{
  var cusno = document.getElementById("cusno").value;
  console.log("Cus No Is :" + cusno);
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<cfoutput>#dir1st#</cfoutput>functions/ajax/invoices.cfc?method=getRegularInvoice",
          data: { 'cusno': cusno  },
          success: function(data){
            console.log("Data Is :" + data);
            $('#thetable tr').not(':first').not(':last').remove();
            var html = '';
            //console.log(data);
            var opts = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(opts, function(i, d) {
              //console.log("onceoff=" + d.onceoff);
              html += '<tr>'
                + '<td><a onclick="edititem('+ d.refid +')"><i class="text-primary fas fa-edit"></i></a>' + d.code + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + d.description + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + d.qty + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + d.price + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + d.total + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + d.dep + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + d.onceoff + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + d.regday + '/' + d.regmonth + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + d.payment_type + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + '<a onclick="if (!confirm(\'Are you sure?\')) return false;"  href="invoice_regular_delitem.cfm?cusno=<cfoutput>#URL.cusno#</cfoutput>&refid='+ d.refid +'"><i class="text-danger fas fa-trash"></i></a>' + '</td>'
                + '</tr>';

            })
            //console.log("html="+html);

            $('#thetable tr').first().after(html);

          }
        })
};
```

The table displays and all my columns are correct, however, onceoff column should return a Yes or No value, however, it returns True or false.
In the table it is a varchar column so can't be that, see below cfdump so you can see the result

[image]

Here is my cfc code that results in the above

```
  <cffunction name="getRegularInvoice" access="remote" output="false" returnformat="json">
  <cfargument name="cusno" type="any" required="true">

    <cfquery name="getitems" datasource="#datasrc#">
        SELECT *
        FROM reg_invoice_items
        WHERE cusno = '#arguments.cusno#'
        ORDER BY code asc
    </cfquery>

    <cfset returnArray = arrayNew(1)>

      <cfloop query="getitems">

          <cfset data = structNew() />
          <cfset data['refid'] = #getitems.refid# />
          <cfset data['code'] = #getitems.code# />
          <cfset data['description'] = #getitems.description# />
          <cfset data['qty'] = #getitems.qty# />
          <cfset data['price'] = #getitems.price# />
          <cfset data['total'] = #getitems.total# />
          <cfset data['originalprice'] = #getitems.originalprice# />
          <cfset data['disc'] = #getitems.disc# />
          <cfset data['exvat'] = #getitems.exvat# />
          <cfset data['location'] = #getitems.location# />
          <cfset data['costnon'] = #getitems.costnon# />
          <cfset data['ajustnon'] = #getitems.ajustnon# />
          <cfset data['regmonth'] = #getitems.regmonth# />
          <cfset data['regday'] = #getitems.regday# />
          <cfset data['onceoff'] = "#getitems.once_off#" />
          <cfset data['dep'] = #getitems.dep# />
          <cfset data['payment_type'] = #getitems.payment_type# />
          <cfset data['currency'] = #getitems.currency# />


          <cfset arrayAppend(returnArray,data) />
      </cfloop>
      <cfreturn returnArray />
```

And finally here is the output of the table, onceoff should say "No"

[image]

Comment: What version of CF? Sounds like this issue [How to prevent SerializeJSON from changing Yes/No/True/False strings to boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867728/how-can-i-prevent-serializejson-from-changing-yes-no-true-false-strings-to-boole). FWIW, it's fixed in CF2018 (not sure about 2016).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SerializeJSON from changing Yes/No/True/False strings to boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867728/how-can-i-prevent-serializejson-from-changing-yes-no-true-false-strings-to-boole).
The workaround is to append a space to the value, so CF treats it as a string. Trim the extra space in your JS code if needed

Comment: Not related to your issue, but it's strongly recommended to use `cfqueryparam` on query parameters for sql-i protection. Also, no need for any pound signs in the cfset statements, i.e. Use `<cfset data['dep'] = getitems.dep />` instead of `<cfset data['dep'] = #getitems.dep# />`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which version of CF you're using, but ... there's one other option for queries in ColdFusion 2016+. Using the new [query serialization settings](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/application-variables.html) in your Application.cfc will preserve the `yes/no` values as strings AND convert the query into a jQuery compatible array of structures - automatically. Obviously being application level settings, they'll apply to *all* queries within the application.

- **serialization.serializeQueryAs = "struct"** - Automatically serialize *all* queries in the application as an array of structures (instead of the weird format CF uses by default).
- **serialization.preserveCaseForQueryColumn = true** - Preserve the case of query column names (instead of converting everything to upper case).

---

**Application.cfc**

```
component {
    this.name = "Your_Application_Name_Here";
    this.serialization.serializeQueryAs = "struct";
    this.serialization.preserveCaseForQueryColumn = true;
}
```

**DemoComponent.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="getData" access="remote" returntype="query">

    <!--- DEMO query. Note, manual queries MUST include column data types --->
    <cfset local.getItems = QueryNew("onceoff,exvat"
                              , "varchar,varchar"
                              , [{exvat : "yes",onceoff : "no"}]
                           )>

        <cfreturn local.getItems>
    </cffunction>   
</cfcomponent>
```

**Result**

```
[{"onceoff":"no","exvat":"yes"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi All the comment Ageax was correct. Its a ColdFusion bug,
I just added white space then trim the value later and it worked perfectly.

Thanks very much